# Why does the first instruction print 24 and the next one print 8?

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()   
{
   int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};   
   int *ptr = arr; 
   printf("Size of arr[] %d\n", sizeof(arr)); 
   printf("Size of ptr %d", sizeof(ptr)); 
   return 0; 
}
```

What is the difference between the two `printf` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the wikipedia article on how [sizeof works on arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Application_to_arrays). Essentially, it is returning the bytes required to store the entire array. In this case you have 6 ints, so this turns into `sizeof(int) * 6` = `4 * 6` = `24`

However, the second `sizeof` is getting the size of an int pointer. Your 64-bit machine has `64/8` = `8` byte pointers. Note that while pointers and arrays are usually considered the "same" in C, this is one of the areas where the behavior differs.

Comment: They differ in all areas. A pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer, but an array is converted to a pointer to the first element on access in all but 4 limited exceptions detailed in [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)